# Image on canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I make UI using canvas.I want that when user touch on screen then there is an image is shown on that canvas so please help me .I want this when user touch the screen.The image is taken by drawable if there is any way to show this image on (x,y) coordinates then tell me Thanks ??

```
public class caanvas extends View {
public Canvas canvas1=new Canvas();
    public float firstcord=0f,secndcord=0f,thirdcord=0f,forthcord=0f,fifthcord=0f,sixcord=0f,sevencord=0f,eightcord=0f;
    public float widthborder=0f;
    public float h = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    public float w = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    public caanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);

        widthborder=w/72f;
        firstcord=w/2.88f;
        secndcord=w/1.5f;
        thirdcord=w/18f;
        forthcord=w/1.035f;
        fifthcord=h/4.2f;
        sixcord=h/2.46f;
        sevencord=h/1.63f;
        eightcord=h/1.28f;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas1=canvas;


        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);


        paint.setStrokeWidth(widthborder);

        canvas.drawLine(firstcord, fifthcord, firstcord, eightcord, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(secndcord, fifthcord, secndcord, eightcord, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(thirdcord, sixcord, forthcord, sixcord, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(thirdcord, sevencord, forthcord, sevencord, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        float x = ev.getX();
        float y = ev.getY();
        switch (ev.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Showimage();
                Log.i("Tag","Start");
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
    public void Showimage()
    {
        Bitmap mFinalbitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cross);
        canvas1.drawBitmap(mFinalbitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: did you read `Canvas` API?

Comment: everything you need is there

Comment: Now there is an error my app is crash when i touch on the screen

Comment: please answr me i am new on canvas

Comment: What's the error saying?

Comment: 05-26 22:07:15.361 30449-30449/com.example.asad.tictoe A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xf8 in tid 30449 (ple.asad.tictoe)

Comment: this error i have face when i touch on screen